# Call a function from command line and pass variables into that fuction

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell-script

I am new to bash scripting. I want to create a script where I can execute a specific function from it with its variables.

Like for example

```
#!/bin/bash

fun1(){
echo "Hello $name"
}
fun2(){
echo "Bye $name"
}
```

How can I execute it like `bash myscript.sh --fun1 --name xyz`

Comment: You'll need to use an option parsing tool that can handle long opts, like getopt: [getopt(1) man page](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/util-linux/getopt.1.en.html), [sample bash usage](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/-/blob/master/misc-utils/getopt-example.bash)

Comment: @glennjackman can you give me an example script using that tool? I saw the man page but everything went over my head :-(

Comment: Did you look at the sample script I linked?

Comment: Also, there will be lots of examples on Stack Overflow: search for "[bash] getopt" is a good place to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command line parsing tools are not required, you can parse by yourself: that's not really more complicated and you will learn many thing.

Arguments to a command are $1, $2,... $# is the number of arguments. `shift` shifts all arguments: the content of $1 is dropped, then $2 is put in $1, $3 in $2, etc...

```
#!/bin/bash

fun1(){
echo "Hello $name"
}
fun2(){
echo "Bye $name"
}

while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
    case $1 in
       '--fun1') fun2exec="fun1" ;;
       '--fun2') fun2exec="fun2" ;;
       '--name') name="$2" ; shift ;;
       *) echo "argument error"; exit 1 ;;
    esac
    shift
done

if [ -z "$fun2exec" ] ; then
    echo "unspecified function"
    exit 2
fi
if [ -z "$name" ] ; then
    echo "unspecified name"
    exit 3
fi

$fun2exec

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to transform long options to short ones [how-can-i-use-long-options-with-the-bash-getopts-builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022592/how-can-i-use-long-options-with-the-bash-getopts-builtin). Then evaluate the short options to call functions and pass variables:

```
#!/bin/bash

fun1(){
echo "Hello $name"
}
fun2(){
echo "Bye $name"
}

for arg in "$@"; do
  shift
  case "$arg" in
  '--fun1')   set -- "$@" '-f'   ;;
  '--fun2')   set -- "$@" '-g'   ;;
  '--name')   set -- "$@" '-n'   ;;
  *)          set -- "$@" "$arg" ;;
  esac
done

exec_fun1=false
exec_fun2=false
while getopts "n:fg" opt ; do
  case "$opt" in
  n) name=${OPTARG} ;;
  f) exec_fun1=true ;;
  g) exec_fun2=true ;;
  esac
done

if $exec_fun1; then fun1 $name ; fi
if $exec_fun2; then fun2 $name ; fi
```

This is not handy if you have many functions in your script. Then it would be easier to make it callable as

```
bash myscript.sh --fun fun_name --name xyz
```